# Error: Network Error Axios - Image React Native

Tags: android, react-native, axios

I'm trying to post an Image to server but axios throw an error saying

> [Error: Network Error]

I created a `bodyFormData` and appended the following

```
bodyFormData.append('image', {
          name: imgName,
          type: 'image/jpeg',
          uri: this.state.image,
        });
```

where my `imageName` is just a string and the `this.state.image` is the file path `file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/0cccb0f1-375b-44b8-b15b-4625536a8d63.jpg`

**Axios Call**

```
const addProduct = async product => {
  try {
    var prod = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: baseURL + 'addProduct',
      data: product,
      headers: {
    'content-type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${product._boundary}`,
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
      },
    });
    return prod;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

After a lot of trials I understand that in `bodyFormData` even I write any kind of JSON object:

```
const oj = {
          name: 'a',
          c: 8,
        }

bodyFormData.append('image', obj  );
```

**it throws me the same error**

> [Error: Network Error]

Kindly please drop the best possible solution for the problem.

Comment: Does the API work with Postman ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan yes sir API works perfectly with postman !!

Comment: try removing the  boundary=${product._boundary} in the headers

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan tried it, same issue sir

Comment: This is the header value i use and i also add the auth header 
'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data`,
            'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
            'Accept': 'application/json',

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan , im totally stocked and annyoyed - all the examples on internet is as similar as what i have written but still things working on postman but not working with react native :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213493/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-ayush-agarwal).

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented this (working) code

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', {
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  name: `myname.jpeg`,
  uri: isAndroid() ? uri : uri.replace('file://', ''),
});
```

and with this header in the api call

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

It's very similar to your code - maybe the **uri** part then ?

Comment: this does not help me :(

Comment: Same issue here , I just found that it works okay on iOS device but doesn't work on Android , Each time i do it it throw network error

Comment: Network Error
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:80:22 in handleError
- node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:39 in